# Change Usercontrol's Textbox.Text Value Through a Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

So I have a usercontrol on winforms that contains a textbox. I have a form that has a button other than the form the usercontrol is placed on. How do I change the usercontrol's textbox.text data when I click the button from another form? I'm using VB.NET.

If both were forms, I can just code something like this under the button_click event since the access identifier for controls on winforms under VB.NET is Friend...

```
Form1.Textbox1.Text = "Hello"
```

This, however, doesn't work on usercontrols. How do I do something like this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a Text property in ur usercontrol which handles the your textbox.text property initially.

```
Public Class MyUserControl

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)] _
    [Browsable(True)] _
    Public Shadow Property Text As String
        Get
            Return textBox1.Text
        End Get
        Set(Value As String)
            textBox1.Text = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Now you can set text like this

```
MyUserControl1.Text = "This is My Text"
```

Also create another property in that form where the UserControl has placed

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Property UserControlText As String
        Get
            Return MyUserControl1.Text
        End Get
        Set(Value As String)
            MyUserControl1.Text = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And you can access that control from another form by using this code

```
Form1 frmForm = DirectCast(Application.OpenForms("Form1"), Form1)
If frmForm IsNot Nothing Then
    frmForm.UserControlText = "Value from different form"
End If
```

Comment: Hi @Shell, thank you for your reply. With a few minor tweaks, I got it to work, thank you very much for this. This line... [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)] _
    [Browsable(True)] _ doesn't work.

Comment: These are the attributes to display the property at design time and the assigned property at design time never get lost on project build. BTW, what is the problem u r getting?

Comment: The code window displays the code with blue zigzag lines, which means the intellisense cannot detect anything like it. Am I missing any libraries that are to be included?

Comment: yeah it might be [System.ComponentModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel(v=vs.110).aspx). [DesignerSerializationVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibility(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Browsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) both attributes requires this namespace to be imported.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Will try it out and get back to you :)